# Model failed to converge with max|grad| How can I solve this problem?

Tags: lme4

I'm using glmer in lme4 package. My formula is like this:

> glmer1 <- glmer(answer ~ (1|subject) + target*major, data=data_identification_analysis, family=binomial)

Then I've got this message:
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.010091 (tol = 0.001, component 1)

My data set is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbbq5bnhpo1i17v/ask_help.xlsx?dl=0

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions when you run `?convergence`?

Comment: I have. For centering and scaling continuous predictor variables, I can't do this as I have no continuous predictor variables.

Comment: And I've done the available optimizers, but still can't solve the problem.

Comment: Hello! I can solve this problem now. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it sorted out!